# Restore Scroll Position From Previous Page Load in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I maintain a site with a lot of dynamic Angular-based content that appears in scrolling feeds.  Ten posts at a time are shown, and an infinite scrolling mechanism allows the user to scroll down and more content is loaded.

I'm being asked to make it so that when a user clicks content, and then ultimately clicks the Back button (no, this isn't a single-page application), that the scroll state is restored to where the user had previously been before they clicked a link.

Is this even doable on a site with dynamic content provided with Angular data bindings?  Granted, the content would be reconstructed as more or less the same as it had been before.  Is there a canonical or recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Store the items of the scroll in a service : data will not be destroyed along with the controller as the user leaves the page. Then you don't need to load all the items back again : when the user presses the back button and the controller is initialized again, you can make it display the content and scroll to the bottom ( or elsewhere ... )

```
myModule.factory( 'service', function(){
 var Service = {
   listOfItems : [],
   positionOfScroll: ''
 }
 return Service;
})

.controller( 'controller', function( Service ){
 $scope.Service = Service;

 $location.hash( Service.positionOfScroll );
 $anchorScroll();

 // all your logic manipulating Service.listOfItems instead of $scope.listOfItems
 // when user scolls, Service.positionOfScoll is updated

});
```

And the template :

```
<div ng-repeat=" item in Service.listOfItems ">{{ item.name }}</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, your solution would work for a single-page application - but in my question I mentioned that I'm not in a SPA.  The back button causes a full page reload and I lose all state.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is not possible without using something like LocalStorage. Once the user leaves your page, your data disappears.

You may want to take a look at the following project on Github: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Good luck!